# Error al crear Static Web App desde una implementación GitHub

Tags: azure, blazor, dotnetcore, github-actions

Pretendo crear una Static Web App a partir de un repositorio GitHub, sin embargo, falla el Workflow y al mirar el detalle del error, veo lo siguiente:
[image: Detalle del error del Workflow]

Observo que no está encontrando algunas clases y esto es porque se encuentran en Dll's externas al proyecto Blazor.

[image: Dll's externas]

¿Bastaría que modifique el archivo .gitignore para que las Dll's estén disponibles? ¿cuál es la mejor práctica en este caso?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Espero poder ayudarte. Hace poco hice una subida de una "Static Web Apps" que esta en un repo privado y se hace por comandos. Lo que implemente en mi caso es la compilación de una app en react con lo que primero se ejecuta:
npm run build -> aqui genera una web estática en la carpeta dist, la cual no tiene "código" es solo html, javascript y Css.

Segun me comento el amigo Yussef se puede implementar apps blazor, aqui la documentación:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor

Lo que si es muy importante que sea del tipo: "Blazor para WebAssembly"(la segunda de la imagen):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso podrías confirmarnos que es de este tipo?